# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

I am trying to implement Array_AGG as CombineFn,
Below is my code:

```
    public static class ArrayAggArray extends Combine.CombineFn<Object, List<Object>, Object[]> {
    @Override
    public List<Object> createAccumulator() {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> addInput(List<Object> accum, Object input) {
      accum.add(input);
      return accum;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<List<Object>> accums) {
      List<Object> merged = new ArrayList<>();
      for (List<Object> accum : accums) {
        merged.add(accum);
      }
      return merged;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] extractOutput(List<Object> accumulator) {
      return accumulator.toArray();
    }
  }
```

When I run the tests, I have been getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection`

I suspect that we cannot create Iterable<List>.
Any sort of other help/input will be appreciated.

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object` is an `Object`-array, not a Collection.

Comment: Should `merged.add(accum);` be `merged.addAll(accum);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code, where you are trying to add a `List<Object>` as an element in the `List<Object>` collection, that is why you have your error here:

```
@Override
public List<Object> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<List<Object>> accums) {
    List<Object> merged = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Object> accum : accums) {
        merged.add(accum);
    }
    return merged;
}
```

the `merged` object has a type of `List<Object>` but your `accum` has a type of `List<Object>` as well, so it cannot cast one to another.

Depending on what you want to do, you have to make another loop over the elements of the `accum` for example:

```
@Override
public List<Object> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<List<Object>> accums) {
    List<Object> merged = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Object> accum : accums) {
        for (Object o : accum) {
            merged.add(o);
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

or you can use `addAll` or other methods you want it to do.

Comment: Even If I do with the nested for loop you suggested, I am getting same exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection. @Markiian Benovskyi

Comment: @SonamGulwani, are you sure you are adding the correct iterated object?

Comment: @Override
    public List<Object> addInput(List<Object> accum, Object input) {
      accum.add(input); //here input is correctly added [1,2]
      return accum;
    }
For sure, I am adding the correct iterated objects.

Comment: My point was about the `mergeAccumulators` method, have a look at it